# Show special field when correct shipping is chosen

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I tried this approach:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', array( $this, 'my_custom_checkout_field') );
add_action('updated_checkout',array( $this, 'my_custom_checkout_field'));

public function my_custom_checkout_field(){

    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
    if($chosen_shipping == 'zasilkovna'){
        include_once('special-field.php');
    }
}
```

However, the special field does not appear when user clicks the shipping method. User needs to manually refresh the page, which is not good.

I need to hook myself on the ajax and show the field when correct shipping is clicked.

I know the jqery is firing the action, but am not quite sure how to hook on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the change event on the field:

```
$('select.shipping-field').on('change', function()) {
   $.post(
       ajaxurl, 
       {
           action: 'shipping_special',
           data: 'your data here..'
       }, 
       function(response){
           // The response should contain your special field HTML
       }
   );
});
```

You can pass the current shipping select option

Then your theme's `functions.php` file needs to have the action to return your special field, if the shipping is `zasilkovna`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_shipping_special', 'shipping_special_field' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_shipping_special', 'shipping_special_field' );

function shipping_special_field() {
    // Return your special field HTML here
}
```

See [wp_ajax__requestaction](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax__requestaction/), this [tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/) from WPMUDev or this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722427/519924);